# Displaying JSON data in a div using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am missing something here in my code because I want to display JSON data in a `div` which is `#searchcontainer` upon initial load of the page
but all I got was an empty `div`.

```
var Sites = [
{"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "FLS Denmark", "Model_Number": "12345"},
{ "country_name": "Zaire", "latitude": -20, "longitude": 30, "status": "OK", "site_name": "FLS Zaire", "Model_Number": "67890" },
{ "country_name": "Vietnam", "latitude": 16, "longitude": 106, "status": "NO", "site_name": "FLS Vietnam", "Model_Number": "1111" }]

var DefaultText = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < Sites.length; i++)
{
DefaultText += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
DefaultText += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png" onclick="DisplayProfileCard();"/>';
DefaultText += '<div id="imagedetail">';

DefaultText += '<span class="details">Product Type:'+ Sites[index].Model_Number +'</span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Version / Size <img class="row_one_icon lightbulb_icon" id="lightbulb" src="src/images/lightbulb1.png" onClick="LightBulb()" /><img id="convert" class="row_one_icon arrow_icon" src="src/images/arrow_Off.png" onClick="Conversion()"/><img id="lightning" class="row_one_icon" src="src/images/lightningOff.png" onClick="Lightning()"/><img id="bullseye" class="row_one_icon bullseye" src="src/images/bullseye_off.png" onClick="BullsEye()"/></span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend <img class="row_one_icon ribbon" src="src/images/ribbon1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon map" src="src/images/map1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon paper_stack" id="paper" src="src/images/paper_stack_Off.png" onclick="PaperStack()"/><img class="row_one_icon chain" id="chain" src="src/images/chain_Off.png" onClick="ChainLink()"/></span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
DefaultText += '</div>';
DefaultText += '</div>';
}
$('#searchcontainer').append(DefaultText);
```

Comment: I would argue that `Sites[index]` is likely undefined since `index` is somehow undefined since it is not declared anywhere in your code. Did you mean `Sites[i]`?

Comment: debugging 101 ... Browsers have a **developer** tools console, for **developers** who are **developing** to see errors ... your code produces `ReferenceError: index is not defined` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Index` was undefined one.use with `i` .And better wrap code with `document.ready`.its perform the function after document loaded

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var Sites = [
{"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "FLS Denmark", "Model_Number": "12345"},
{ "country_name": "Zaire", "latitude": -20, "longitude": 30, "status": "OK", "site_name": "FLS Zaire", "Model_Number": "67890" },
{ "country_name": "Vietnam", "latitude": 16, "longitude": 106, "status": "NO", "site_name": "FLS Vietnam", "Model_Number": "1111" }]

var DefaultText = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < Sites.length; i++)
{
DefaultText += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
DefaultText += '<img id="productimage" src="src/images/retrofit.png" onclick="DisplayProfileCard();"/>';
DefaultText += '<div id="imagedetail">';

DefaultText += '<span class="details">Product Type:'+ Sites[i].Model_Number +'</span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Version / Size <img class="row_one_icon lightbulb_icon" id="lightbulb" src="src/images/lightbulb1.png" onClick="LightBulb()" /><img id="convert" class="row_one_icon arrow_icon" src="src/images/arrow_Off.png" onClick="Conversion()"/><img id="lightning" class="row_one_icon" src="src/images/lightningOff.png" onClick="Lightning()"/><img id="bullseye" class="row_one_icon bullseye" src="src/images/bullseye_off.png" onClick="BullsEye()"/></span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Estimated annual Spend <img class="row_one_icon ribbon" src="src/images/ribbon1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon map" src="src/images/map1.png"/><img class="row_one_icon paper_stack" id="paper" src="src/images/paper_stack_Off.png" onclick="PaperStack()"/><img class="row_one_icon chain" id="chain" src="src/images/chain_Off.png" onClick="ChainLink()"/></span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Site name / manufacturer</span>';
DefaultText += '<span class="details">Selling Sales Eng</span>';
DefaultText += '</div>';
DefaultText += '</div>';
}
$('#searchcontainer').append(DefaultText);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much works like a charm! Now I see what am I missing :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Sites[i].Model_Number` instead of `Sites[index].Model_Number`.